# How to call "isInitialStickyBroadcast()" and avoid problems on 1.6?

Tags: android

`isInitialStickyBroadcast()` is obviously only available after 2.0 (SDK 5).

I'm getting this error:

> "Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
>   java.lang.VerifyError"

It's only happening on 1.6. Android 2.0 and up doesn't have any problems, but that's the main point of all.

I can't catch the Error/Exception (java.lang.VerifyError), and I know it's being caused by calling isInitialStickyBroadcast() which is not available in SDK 4, that's why it's wrapped in the SDK check.

I just need this BroadcastReceiver to work on 2.0+ and not break in 1.6, it's an app in the market, the UNDOCK feature is needed for users on 2.0+ but obviously not in 1.6 but there is a fairly substantial number of users still on 1.6.

Here's an easy-to-read version of part of the code I'm using. Notice that it's wrapped in an SDK check to only run on 2.0+, but the VerifyError is still showing up.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mUndockedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //FROM ECLAIR FORWARD, BEFORE DONUT THIS INTENT WAS NOT IMPLEMENTED
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 5)
        {
            if (!isInitialStickyBroadcast()) {
                //Using constant instead of Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE to avoid problems in older SDK versions
                int dockState = intent.getExtras().getInt("android.intent.extra.DOCK_STATE", 1);
                if (dockState == 0)
                {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: As I commented yesterday on your other version of this question, if you need to use APIs that aren't available and can't just use constants, then check out the advice on using reflection on the Android Developers' site:  
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html

Comment: Yes, I made it work using reflection, based on the answer below from commonsware, sorry, I didn't see your other comment mentioning the link and all about reflection on the other question. That worked though, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that while you would not be executing `isInitialStickyBroadcast()`, the classloader attempts to resolve all methods when the class is loaded, so your SDK 4 devices fail at that point, since there is no `isInitialStickyBroadcast()`.

You have two main options:

1. Use reflection.
2. Create two editions of your `BroadcastReceiver`, as public classes in their own files. One has the SDK 4 logic, one has the SDK 5+ logic. Register the one you want based on an SDK check at the time you call `registerReceiver()`.